# Select entries that appear more than 4 times

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

I have 2 tables, one contains people and another contains enrolments with a reference to the people id's. I have to create a view where only results that appear in the enrolments more than 4 times are included.

I think I need to use `count()` but I can't get it to count what I need it to. How do you output a table that only includes the people that appear in the enrolment table more than 4 times?

Here are some sample rows and what I tried to do:

Table `enrolment`:

| id | student |
| --- | --- |
| 462583 | 1010093 |
| 464457 | 1010093 |
| 469823 | 1010093 |
| 471345 | 1010093 |
| 473239 | 1010093 |
| 475371 | 1010093 |
| 477419 | 1010093 |
| 479797 | 1010093 |
| 572312 | 1010138 |
| 577147 | 1010138 |
| 578866 | 1010138 |
| 580596 | 1010138 |
| 582497 | 1010138 |

Students 1010093 and 1010138 would fit the criteria because they appear more than 4 times. But there are many students with fewer entries.

Table `people`:

(id is the id that enrolment refers to in student column).

| id | uniid | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10000019 | 8758024 | Emery Schubert |
| 10000021 | 9808692 | Ann Moore |
| 10000025 | 9833783 | Zhen-Tian Chang |
| 10000026 | 7610575 | John Carrick |
| 10000035 | 9837669 | Pamela Mort |
| 10000037 | 9049091 | Sami Korell |
| 10000049 | 9869271 | Mengistu Amberber |
| 10000051 | 9375982 | Colin Fong |
| 10000053 | 9146607 | Dianne Montgomerie |
| 10000073 | 9804805 | Grant Walter |
| 1010093 | 2220747 | Barbara Fremder |
| 1010138 | 2240781 | Say-Kit Ezergailis |
| 1011114 | 2119574 | Evangelos McDonald |
| 1011293 | 2291530 | Grace Hoekstra |
| 1011474 | 2261154 | Chee Jairaj |

My attempt was this:

```
create or replace view Q1(uniid,name) as
select people.uniid, people.name
from people left outer join enrolments on (people.id = enrolments.student)
group by people.uniid, people.name having count(enrolments.student) > 4;
```

Sample output:

| uniid | name |
| --- | --- |
| 3100280 | Mia Wiech |
| 3225571 | Cora Prochaska |
| 3335780 | Vinh Ha |
| 3255146 | Moyang Liu Hongtao |
| 3365147 | Frances Ellers |
| 3327487 | Keerati Meechowna |
| 3397549 | Shane Dinham |
| 3372084 | Benjamin Tenenbaum |
| 3252837 | Kayserline McFarlane |
| 3350110 | Jose Varas |
| 3258061 | Alison Lettich |
| 3345581 | Snehal Sethu |

Comment: Basic SQL questions are better directed to https://stackoverflow.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate enrolments, filter, and only then join to people:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW q1 AS
SELECT p.uniid, p.name
FROM  (
   SELECT student
   FROM   enrolments
   GROUP  BY 1
   HAVING count(*) > 4
   ) e
JOIN   people p ON p.id = e.student;
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves half the problem but my output is still incorrect for some reason but that's probably due to a mistake in what I'm doing in terms of filtering, the student needs to have more than 4 distinct enrolments (although I think the enrolments for each student should already be distinct, perhaps not?). Also, what does the "GROUP BY 1" do? Cheers

Comment: @HarryP: `GROUP BY 1` references the first `SELECT` list item, short for `GROUP  BY student`. Only you can tell us what's unique / distinct in your table. Please direct any similar question to https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Thank you so much, it works now after modifying some parameters for count(), I spent so long on it, I really appreciate your help. I'll be sure to ask on stack overflow instead next time.